# Android Best practice for background task

Tags: android, background, task, handler, postdelayed

I have custom hardware, with a custom Android Launcher app running. I need to read an ADC chip (ADS7871) at a set interval.
Currently this is being done using a handler, but it seems the postdelayed value is not maintained if other tasks are operating in the background.

Is there a better method for performing a task at set intervals, which will take priority?

Many Thanks,
Nigel

Comment: What sort of interval? Seconds... or milliseconds? Keep in mind that Android is not a realtime OS.

Comment: I'm looking for milliseconds, any ideas?

Comment: You'd either need to go to kernel level if you want to do it in software. I haven't quite dug that deep, so many I'm missing something. I had one time-critical data acquisition project where I simply added a micro to handle the synchronous input and then allowed android to read the buffer every second or so.

Comment: Makes sense, maybe I'll add something to the adc driver to buffer values at a timed interval and return the result. Thanks!